# Python scripts not running with Mod_WSGI on Apache2 / OS X El Capitan

Tags: python, apache, mod-wsgi, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to run a Python script with help of Mod_WSGI (installed with PIP as GrahamDumpleton suggests in https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/98) on Apache2 / OS X El Capitan system. But I'm still failing after two days of trial and error..:S

The problem is that the script is not executed, but treated as a static file - showing the code in my browser.

What am I not seeing or doing wrong? My config is listed below.

Python script:

```
def application(environ, start_response):
    status = '200 OK'
    output = 'Hello World!'

    response_headers = [('Content-type', 'text/plain'),
                        ('Content-Length', str(len(output)))]

    start_response(status, response_headers)

    return [output]
```

httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName local.flipflopinteractive.com
    ServerAdmin koen@flipflopinteractive.com
    DocumentRoot "/Users/kdesterik/Sites/001_0001/dist/"
    ErrorLog "/Users/kdesterik/Sites/001_0001/dist/error.log"
    AddHandler cgi-script .py
    <Directory "/Users/kdesterik/Sites/001_0001/dist/">
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews ExecCGI
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts part which maps localhost to above ServerName:

```
127.0.0.1       local.flipflopinteractive.com
```

httpd.conf part which loads mod_wsgi:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/mod_wsgi/server/mod_wsgi-py27.so
```

Any help will be super appreciated.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a line like this pointing to your script in your httpd-vhosts.conf:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /myapp /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/gorilla/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi
```